# How to create a container in php then customise it in CSS

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, css, html

I am a newbie so I think i have worded this right.

I am using wordpress and have an if clause to echo something about returns policy for certain items.

```
    function christmas_returns() {
    global $product;

    if ( ! $product ) {
        return;
    }

    $product_id = $product->get_id();



    if ( has_term( 'kimonos-and-gowns', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            
        echo 'test';
    }


    }


    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'christmas_returns', 5 );
```

I think what i need to do is give this a div class so then I can select it with CSS and give it a boarder and colour etc.

I've tried to wrap 'test' around   but I just cannot get it to work.

I'm not 100% sure im doing it right but essentially all im trying to do is give this code its own selector in CSS so I can give it a boarder and make it colourful.

Thanks

Comment: Is test is outputed? if yes then include the html/css that you tried to output as well

Comment: You just need to include the HTML in the string you’re outputting. Then add styles to your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks guys I got it to work now